# save to csv - numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I'm trying to append the filenames of the images during training into a csv file, but getting an error. I can print the values okay but cannot append to csv file for some reason. Here is the full code:

```
  File "train_filename.py", line 140, in <module>
    names_preds.append() + '\n'
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

```
        with open('preds_base_model_teste1016.csv','a') as fd:
            #dict_writer = csv.writer(fd)
            #dict_writer.writerow('Target' + '\n')
            #dict_writer.writerow( ','.join(map(str, preds.detach().tolist())) + '\n')
            #dict_writer.writerow('Prediction' + '\n')
            #dict_writer.writerow( ','.join(map(str, targets.detach().tolist())) + '\n')
            #fd.write('Target' + '\n')
            fd.write(','.join(map(str, preds.detach().tolist())) + '\n')
            #fd.write('Prediction' + '\n')
            fd.write( ','.join(map(str, targets.detach().tolist())) + '\n')
            #fd.write('Image_Name' + '\n')
            np.append(paths)
            #fd.write([filename])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concatenate` instead of `append` as described [in the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html).

It does look like you are trying to add nothing to the array, however.

You should use it like this:

`names_preds.concatenate(some_value)` where the value inside `concatenate` is what you want to add to the array.

To save a numpy array to a csv file, there is an easier way:

```
numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", names_preds, delimiter=",")
```

See details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62802390/edit) answer.

Replace your line:

```
np.append(paths)
```

with

```
with open('preds_base_model_teste1016.csv','a') as fd:
    np.savetxt(fd, names_preds, delimiter=",")
```

That will append all of the paths to the file you already specified.

Update:

Per your question in the comment, to put multiple arrays together so you end up with columns, you could try:

```
with open('preds_base_model_teste1016.csv','a') as fd:
    np.savetxt(fd, list(zip(a,b,c)), delimiter=",")
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` are the arrays you want as columns.

Comment: Thanks! But i get an erro   File "train_filename.py", line 140
    names_preds.concatenate('\n\')
                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: It's name_preds that i am trying to append to the csv file.

Comment: @AA2018-2020 see update. You can use `savetxt` to do all the hard work.

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U61') and format specifier ('%.18e')

Comment: Is it do with the string i am trying to save to the csv file: Processed_Images/2020-03-Sequence-p4-Day-3_Position046.png

Comment: @AA2018-2020 I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. I updated my answer with exactly what you should need.

Comment: Many Thanks @matthew-salvatore-viglione. One last question if i would like to save each value as column next to each other for example A(Listof rows), B(List of rows), C(List rows) at the moment it all getting saved under one column. Just so i can compare the values. I have tried np.column_stack but this split them each value into a column and not one column with the rows underneath it. Many Thanks